# Using pull request Instead of merge in working on feature branches. Is it git flow?

Tags: github, git-flow, strategy-pattern

## What i wondered

I want to use pull request than merge in working on feature branches. Is it git flow too?

### Why this think is started?

1. I prefer to use pull request than merge for source code review.
2. Don't wanna remain 'commit history' of  my feature branches in master.

### Please show any recommanded git repo. for examples

I want to find repository that following git flow for study about git flow.

Would you recommand any repository on git flow? I will mark star and follow repository yours or others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub's [Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom) repository is a good example of an open source project where contributors create a branch, commit and push to that branch, and when ready, open a pull request. If the pull request is accepted by the project's owners it is merged. Here is a link to [merged pull requests](https://github.com/atom/atom/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aclosed%20is%3Amerged).

> I want to use pull request than merge in working on feature branches. Is it git flow too?

Creating a new branch, working on that branch, and opening a pull request for review and to eventually merge your changes is best practice for both Git Flow and [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

> I prefer to use pull request than merge for source code review.

Yes, this is great.  You can harness the power of [protected branches and required status checks](https://help.github.com/enterprise/admin/guides/developer-workflow/about-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks/) to automate testing and ensure branches cannot be merged until all of your required criteria is met.

Hope that helped - let me know if this did not answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It will be surely help

Answer (score 0):

You can install git extensions to support git-flow. The AVH version of git-flow has some great features:
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh

It has support for hooks (custom scripts):
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Reference:-Hooks-and-Filters#hooks

You can install to the AVH version on a Mac using:

```
brew install git-flow-avh
```

To support a pull request in git flow you can add a script:

```
.git/hooks/post-flow-feature-publish.sh
```

When running the command:

```
git flow feature my-feature publish
```

Git flow will push code to the feature branch and call the hook script to create the PR.

Comment: This is interesting, but what would be the script contents?